# Evaluate XML Find Bad Character?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have some XML coming from a remote (Java) web service into my c# console app, it is written to a Microsoft SQL Server XML column via a stored procedure. Sometimes the XML has a bad character somewhere and SQL Server is not giving enough information about where the problem exactly is.

I would like to evaluate the XML before the database-write happens, and of course I have no XSD.

What is a good way to evaluate every part of the XML for "regular conformance" before writing to the database? I am using .NET 4.0, C#.

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get? Are you using parameters?

Comment: Just load it up to an xml document or somesuch. Trap the exception, quarntine the data, etc. Assuming of course that it's broke when you get it off the web service as opposed to being messed up encoding wise when you fire it to the sp.

Comment: Just open the document with `XmlReader.Create()` then loop over every node with `XmlReader.Read()`.

Comment: Is it really a bad character...or is the code not setup to read the proper character set and the bad character is a valid character in its set, say the code is reading ASCII on a UTF-8 scenario???

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility, I would recommend doing XML Schema Validation on all XML dat that you retrieve in 3rd party services.

Xml Schema validation will ensure that every element of an XML document is valid against it's defined contract.

You should consider making the Xml Schema Validation optional, as it introduces an overhead, that you might want to prevent in production environments. But in development and testing environments it can be quite beneficial to get detail validation error information from all your 3rd party services.

Answer (score -3):

You can try sanitizing your xml which might help a little bit: http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/hexadecimal-value-0-is-an-invalid-character/

That link really only helps filter invalid characters, most of the time, that will not be enough nor helpful (however I still recommended filtering unknown characters for security).

I think for checking if tags are valid or not, you can use a try catch. If the try catch is returning problems on line 1 then, the problem could be that you don't have a root element in your xml? Or it could be that your encoding is incorrect for the xml document. They should return different errors.

Comment: -1: sanitizing garbage still produces garbage. You have no idea what the author of the document thought the bad characters represented.

Comment: You dont need to nessesarily remove the sanitized characters, you can translate them to tags which are treated like comments, or you can throw an exception upon finding them on the exact line that you find them. Just because the example shows one way of filtering doesn't mean that you have to delete or santize. You can do whatever you want with those characters

Comment: Anything except for understanding why they are present.